# Ag-Grid 'agSetColumnFilter' Customization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Can i change the default behaviour of agSetColumnFilter of ag-grid. I can change the filter values by using values: paramter in filterParams. But Since Set Filter performs exact serarch with cell Value so can i update it to Contains search instead of Exact Search.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. Under column definition.

```
{
filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
filterParams: { 
    values: ["custom1", "custom2"] 
}
```

Also read about [https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-filtering/#example-set-filter] to load the values Async.

Comment: could you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450872/search-function-of-agsetcolumnfilter-customization?noredirect=1#comment115715821_65450872

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not supported. The whole point of the agSetColumnFilter is to match a (hopefully) small set of values contained in a column. If you have so many different values that you need a 'contains' filter, then the setFilter is probably not appropriate anyway.

That said, if you want custom behavior in a filter, that is not accommodated by a standard filter your best is probably to write your own custom filter. The documentation for custom filters can be found at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#custom-filter-example

Answer (score 0):

Apply List of Key words to setfilter model in the following way

**Column Definition:**

```
const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
    // explicitly configure column to use the Set Filter
    { field: 'entityStatus.code', filter: 'agSetColumnFilter' },
]);
```

**Custom Filter:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (gridAPI) {
        const model = gridAPI.api.getFilterModel() // get previous filter model
        const currentModel = {
            'entityStatus.code': {
                filterType: 'set',
                values: selectedStatus // [ '104' , '503' ]
            }
        }
        const updatedModel = {
            ...model,
            ...currentModel
        }

        if (!isEmpty(selectedStatus)) {
            gridAPI.api.setFilterModel(updatedModel) // apply filter
        } else {
            gridAPI.api.destroyFilter('entityStatus.code') // destroy applied filter in perticular column 
        }
    }
}, [ selectedStatus ])
```